# Is Hosted In-App Purchase only available for IOS6?

Tags: ios5, ios6, in-app-purchase

I want to create an app with in app purchases. As I see, Apple now hosts the contents of non-consumable in-app purchases.

What if I want to support IOS5? Can I send my content to Apple for hosting? Or it is only available for IOS 6?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that hosted content in itunes connect is only available for iOS6. If your app supports iOS 5 you must download the content from your own server or pack it on the bundle and unlock it after the transaction.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial
...."such as covering the new iOS 6 Hosted Downloads feature..."